# Setting the position of the jQuery UI tooltip dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

So I have the following code. I am trying to get tooltips with arrows from the elements they belong to.

```
var topPosition = { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top-10' };
var bottomPosition = { my: 'center top', at: 'center bottom+10' };
$(document).tooltip
({
    tooltipClass: 'top',
    position: topPosition,
    open: function(e,ui){
        var topOfToolTip = ui.tooltip.offset().top;
        var elem = $(e.originalEvent.target);
        if (elem.offset().top < topOfToolTip) {
            pos = {my: 'center top', at: 'center bottom+10'};
            ui.tooltip.position(pos);
            ui.tooltip.addClass("bottom");              
        }           
    } 
});
```

Then I have the following css:

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
}
.ui-tooltip-content::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}

.top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    bottom: -10px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;    
}

.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: -10px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
}
```

So in the code I check if there isnt enough room for the tooltip above the element then I want it to show below. Fine, that works. But my problem is that when that happens the arrow is pointing in the wrong direction. If I manually change the class and the position to use bottom values then it works below but not when I try to get the tooltip to show above.

So the issue is that the position doesnt seem to be setting. So can someone tell me how I do this?

Comment: Working on this. I suspect you're better off using the `position` option with the `using` attribute. I took this example: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style and applied your styling. It's backward still... but this is what I would suggest: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vmmsb9vx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, making use of the `position` option, and the `using` attribute can handle this with a few changes to your CSS.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vmmsb9vx/1/

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
  <a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a> will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p>
  <label for="age">Your age:</label>
  <input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

.ui-tooltip-content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}

.top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
  top: -10px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-color: #666 transparent;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px;
}

.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::after {
  bottom: -10px;
  border-color: #666 transparent;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).tooltip({
  position: {
    my: 'center bottom-20',
    at: 'center top',
    using: function(position, feedback) {
      console.log(feedback);
      $(this).css(position);
      $(this).addClass(feedback.vertical);
    }
  }
});
```

You can see the correct class `top` or `bottom` added to your Tooltip based on the `feedback`. I adjusted your CSS so the arrow pointed the right way in each scenario.

Comment: This worked for me when I was just doing top and bottom. But I am trying to extend it now so I can do left or right. (if the tooltip shows up off the screen then it should go to the other side). So in the using function I check if position.left < 0. If it is I $(this).css(rightPosition);. But the tooltip doesnt move position for me

Comment: There are more elements to `feedback` that you can use to address this. If you send the object to console, you can do something similar to the top/bottom fix.

Comment: I can set the class no problem, so the arrow sets correctly. But my problem is that the tooltips position itself is wrong. In the using function it has a value of -55, so its off the screen a bit. I want to put it to the right of the element if that is the case. I think previously I wasnt setting the position either, jQuery itself, or the browser maybe, was taking care of that. I was just setting the class incorrectly

Comment: Sorry, when I was making the jFiddle I might have found a solution. Ill update when I know for sure

Comment: @discodowney that happens a lot :) A different perspective on the code when you move it into a fiddle.

Comment: It was actually mentioning that feedback could be used that sorted it for me. I use feedback target to determine the position of the tooltip. Cheers for the help.